# Costum walker with sub menu item count

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I have a menu like:

```
-Item1
--Sub1
--Sub2
--Sub3
--Sub4
--Sub5
--Sub6
-Item2
-Item3
```

and want to do some costum stuff after x subitems, so I have to determine when x is reached. I tried to define a variable in my costum class and then increment it in end_el():

```
class Walker_Nav_Menu_Costum extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    var $x = 0;

    function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {

        if ($depth == 1)
        {
            $x++;
        }

        $output .= "<!-- x:".$x."-->";

        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
}
```

but unfortunately its always 1 for every element :-/

How would one do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function your `$x` is local.

You might want to use a static variable:

```
class Walker_Nav_Menu_Costum extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    static $x = 0;

    function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() )
    {
        if ( 1 == $depth ) self::$x++;
        $output .= "<!-- x:".self::$x."-->";
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure I need a static var, stupid me ... thx :)

Comment: You don't necessarily need a static var, you could use a plain object property on the Walker, like `$this->x`

Comment: @djb True. Apparently, I didn't see the object context when writing my answer.